# How to stop div from moving to bottom right

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a project in class to make a website. I have tried what the other answers have said to do but it never works!

```css
.block1 {
  border: 2px dashed #ffffff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 270px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  position: relative;
}

.block2 {
  border: 2px dashed #ffffff;
  width 200px;
  height: 270px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 30%;
  margin-left: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1">
  <p>Everyday life is like programming, I guess. If you love something you can put beauty into it</p>
</div>
<div class="block2">
  <p>The past is behind, learn from it. The future is ahead, prepare for it. The present is here, live it</p>
</div>
```

I've just copy pasted basically what I've done. I'm currently very new and I've only done a little bit of html in my own time and I've learnt all that I have done within the past 3 weeks. My problem is, the  on the left is fine, but the div on the right sits at the very bottom right. I've tried using overflow because I thought the margin might be collapsing but I don't really understand as I'm still very new. I want it to sit at the exact same height and same difference but from the left side of the screen. I tried using margin-left and it still didn't work. Please help me I really don't understand.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood you. But what would you like to do with these to blocks?

Comment: Do you want to display the blocks side by side? there is no clarity in your explanation

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Maybe show a picture? Otherwise, rephrase your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make `.block1` `display:inline-block;` as well

Answer (score -1):

IF you want same CSS to apply on two class then you can give same class name to both class. And in html for newline use `<br>`.
Try this, i think as per i understand.

```css
 .block1 {
    border: 2px dashed #ffffff;
    width: 200px;
    height: 270px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    position: relative;
     display: inline-block;
}
    .block2 {
    margin-top: 10%;
   }
```

```html
<div class="block1"><p>Everyday life is like programming, I guess. If you love something you can put beauty into it</p></div>
<br>
<div class="block1 block2"><p>The past is behind, learn from it. The future is ahead, prepare for it. The present is here, live it</p></div>
```